# AttributeError: Myclass instance has no attribute 'x'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attributeerror

I am trying to select a feature from the layer using my plugin. When working with my plugin in main Python function using QGIS, I receive an AttributeError when I call a class method from within the class itself.
I'm using QGIS 2.8.

Here is my code below:

```
def handle_mouse_down(point):
    """"Manage selection when clicking on the canvas."""

    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    layers = canvas.layers()
    clickTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

    vl_to_query = [l for l in layers if l.name() != u'my_layer_name'][0]
    w = canvas.mapUnitsPerPixel() * 3
    rect = QgsRectangle(
        point.x() - w,
        point.y() - w,
        point.x() + w,
        point.y() + w
    )

    l_rect = canvas.mapSettings().mapToLayerCoordinates(vl_to_query, rect)
    vl_to_query.select(l_rect, False)
    feats = vl_to_query.selectedFeatures()
    vl_to_query.removeSelection()
    clickTool.canvasClicked.disconnect(self.handle_mouse_down)
```

When I run this function am getting an error like

> File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\Myclass\Myclass.py", line 220, in
>   handle_mouse_down point.x() - w,
>   AttributeError: Myclass instance has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Can you include the *actual* error message in your question, it will probably contain more pertinent information.

Comment: **AttributeError: Mycalss instance has no attribute 'x'** This is the Actual error that am facing everytime

Comment: I updated my question please check it

Comment: You probably set `point = Myclass()` somewhere in your code and Myclass has no attribute `x`. It's hard to tell what problem is just by looking at this part of your `Myclass.py` file. How do you call `handle_mouse_down()` method and pass the argument. Did you define `x` attribute for `Myclass` class or inherit from any class which has attribute `x`?

Comment: I agree with @Kadir, the problem is most likely you're calling handle_mouse_down with a Myclass object instead of a QgsPoint object... that's one of the dangers of python, in C (# or ++) etc. you'd be unable to compile because the wrong object is being passed. There is an awesome answer here that should help with your mousedown event https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/programatically-check-for-mouse-click-in-pyqgis and here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108044/getting-coordinates-by-clicking-on-qgis-canvas-with-pyqgis (2nd answer)