# Getting coordinates on click and pass it to dialog using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, python-2.7

I am creating a plugin in which i need to get coordinates by clicking on QGIS canvas so i tried the solution mentionned at [Getting coordinates by clicking on QGIS Canvas with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108044/getting-coordinates-by-clicking-on-qgis-canvas-with-pyqgis) but it didn't work for me , but this one [Programatically check for mouse click in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/programatically-check-for-mouse-click-in-pyqgis) seems working well now i want to pass the coordinates to GUI LineEdit, using QGIS 2.8.6, Python 2.7 and PyQT4 but it's not working so here's my code :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication,QObject
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon

import os.path
from qgis.core import QgsApplication,QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas,QgsMapToolEmitPoint,QgsMapTool

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog
from Proejt_dialog import ProjetDialog
from Proejt_dialog import ProjetDialog as ProjetDialog1
import os.path
class Projet:
   def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.h=0
        self.iface = iface

        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'Projet_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Projet')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Projet')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'Projet')
   def functions(self):
        do stuffs
   def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        tool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):   
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas    
        self.ui = ProjetDialog1()

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
        self.ui.X.setText(str(point[0]))
        self.ui.Y.setText(str(point[1]))
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #Get the click
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

        P=Projet(self) #error

        P.dlg.X.setText(str(point[0]))
        P.dlg.Y.setText(str(point[1]))

    def activate(self):
        pass

    def deactivate(self):
        pass

    def isZoomTool(self):
        return False

    def isTransient(self):
        return False

    def isEditTool(self):
        return True
```

any help please, i'm still new to PyQGIS

**Update :**
i couldn't link the class 'PointTool' to the dialog initialised in the 'Projet' class, so i added a parent parameter which contain the dialog to the 'PointTool' then call it in run function from Projet Class

Comment: check this project code https://github.com/All4Gis/instagram2qgis/blob/master/Insta2QgisDialog.py#L577 do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here's my new code

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication,QObject
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon

import os.path
from qgis.core import QgsApplication,QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas,QgsMapToolEmitPoint,QgsMapTool

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog
from Proejt_dialog import ProjetDialog
from Proejt_dialog import ProjetDialog as ProjetDialog1
import os.path
class Projet:
   def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.h=0
        self.iface = iface

        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'Projet_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Projet')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Projet')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'Projet')
   def functions(self):
        do stuffs
   def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        tool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas(),parent=self) #define this class as parent
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):   
    def __init__(self, canvas,parent=None): #add parent parametre
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas    
        self.ui = ProjetDialog1()
        self.parent = parent

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #Get the click
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

        self.parent.dlg.X.setText(str(point[0])) # call parent(Projet) dialog
        self.parent.dlg.Y.setText(str(point[1]))

    def activate(self):
        pass

    def deactivate(self):
        pass

    def isZoomTool(self):
        return False

    def isTransient(self):
        return False

    def isEditTool(self):
        return True
```

Comment: Besides publishing your solution it would be nice also to add some explanation what was wrong before and how you managed to solve it.

Comment: Please include explanation in the body of your answer, not as comment.